# A "lie" which is not considered a lie because everyone knows it

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, sheker-false

I remember, when I learned Seder Nezikin, that there are trading situations in which a seller lies to a buyer (e.g. exaggerates the merits of his product), but, this is not considered deception, because anyone in the market knows that sellers talk like this, and the buyer should also know that and not believe the seller, and if the buyer did believe - it is his problem because "he is the one who lied to himself".

Now, I cannot find this halacha. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps
[Mishna Nedarim 3:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h33.htm) ?

> ג,א  ארבעה נדרים התירו חכמים--נדרי זירוזין, נדרי הבאי, נדרי שגגות, נדרי אונסין.  נדרי זירוזין:  היה מוכר לו חפץ ואמר, קונם שאיני פוחת לך מן הסלע, והלה אומר קונם שאיני מוסיף לך על השקל, ושניהם רוצים בשלושה דינרין
>
> Four categories of vow were absolved by the rabbis ... *a vow intended to spur someone else into action*: If I was selling someone an object and proclaimed, *I vow against [eating fruit] if I get less than 4 dinars for this!*, and he responded, *Well I vow against [eating fruit] if I give you more than 1 dinar!* ... and in fact both of them want a price of 3 dinars.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was looking for...

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a phrase similar to "he is the one who lied to himself".